# Change of variables for obtaining a unitary group

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, parabolic-pde, schrodinger-operators

Consider the following NLS:

$$i u_t + \Delta u- 2 \operatorname{Re} u = F(u),$$

where $F(u):=(u + \bar{u} + |u|^2)u.$

In [Scattering for the Gross–Pitaevskii equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510080), the authors S. Gustafson, K. Nakanishi, and T.-P. Tsai used a change of variables to get the free evolution as a unitary group:

$$u \mapsto v:=V^{-1}u:= U^{-1} \operatorname{Re} u + i \operatorname{Im}u,$$

where $U:=\sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)^{-1}}$.

Then $v$ satisfies the equation

$$i v_t - \sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)} v = - i V^{-1} i F(V v).$$

I have been trying to understand the motivation of this change of variable but no result! The main obstacles for me is the squire root, I can not see where the square root came from? Any help is appreciated.

**Updates**

I tried to write the equation as a dynamical system of two PDEs, real and imaginary parts, and tried to diagonalized the operator but I couldn't get the same result.

Comment: @LSpice of a paper.

Comment: @LSpice https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510080.pdf

Comment: OK, I have edited [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430844/change-of-variables-for-obtaining-a-unitary-group#comment1108843_430844) in, and deleted my prior comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=u_1+iu_2$, $v=v_1+iv_2$ with $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ being real valued.
What one would like to do is find a $2\times 2$ matrix of real symmetric operators
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$
such that if one lets
$$
\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}\ ,
$$
the free equation $i\partial_t u=-\Delta u+2\Re u$ is equivalent to an evolution for $v$ which is of the form $i\partial_t v=H v$ where $H$ is a real symmetric operator, or rather its complexification.

One could start with general $A,B,C,D$ and see what happens, but with the hindsight provided by the authors of the mentioned article, we know we will be able to arrange for $B,C=0$, and $D={\rm Id}$. Let's go ahead and rename $A=U^{-1}$, for some $U$ TBA.

In terms of real and imaginary components, the equation for $u$ is equivalent to the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\partial_t u_1 &=&   -\Delta u_2\\
\partial_t u_2 &=& \Delta u_1 -2u_1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
while for the components of $v$ we must have
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\partial_t v_1 &=&   H u_2\\
\partial_t v_2 &=& -H u_1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Since we assumed the relations $v_1=U^{-1}u_1$, $v_2=u_2$, we immediately get
$$
\partial_t v_1=-U^{-1}\Delta v_2
$$
which suggests $H=-U^{-1}\Delta$.
But we also get
$$
\partial_t v_2=\partial_t u_2=(\Delta-2)u_1=(\Delta-2)Uv_1
$$
which requires also $H=-(\Delta-2)U$. So consistency for the choice of $H$ needs the equation
$$
-U^{-1}\Delta=(2-\Delta)U
$$
to hold. Assuming $U$ commutes with $\Delta$, we obtain the desired square root formula.

Comment: I think you meant $D=I$

Comment: Yes of course. I just fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to show that the equation
$$
iu_t+\Delta u-2\,{\rm Re}\,u=F(u),\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
with $u=Vv$, is equivalent to
$$i v_t - \sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)} v = - i V^{-1} i F(V v).\label{2}\tag{2}$$

Let me decompose $u=u_1+iu_2$ into real and imaginary parts.
By definition
$$v= [- \Delta (2-\Delta)^{-1}]^{-1/2} u_1 + i u_2,\label{3}\tag{3}$$
hence
$$\sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)} v=(2-\Delta)u_1+i\sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)}u_2.\label{4}\tag{4}$$

I now start from equation (2) and multiply both sides by $Vi$,
$$-u_t+V[i(\Delta-2)u_1+\sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)}u_2]=iF(u).\label{5}\tag{5}$$
I note that
$$V^{-1}(i\Delta u-2iu_1)=i(\Delta-2)u_1+\sqrt{- \Delta (2-\Delta)}u_2.\label{6}\tag{6}$$
Substitution of equation \eqref{6} into equation \eqref{5} gives equation \eqref{1}, so indeed, equations \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are equivalent.